# Android File Upload Control

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbie for android and trying to include a file uploader in android application. But I can't find in any relevant control for that. I want to place a control like [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCOCB.gif)

What should I do for achieving this task?

Comment: cant you upload file from your SD-card or using camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt control for uploading a file in Android. In java we are having a file-chooser to browse the file. in android you have to do this to select a file either from camera or gallery.

final String[] items = new String[] { "Take picture",
                "Choose from Gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    builder.setTitle("Select Image");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.copy_selected);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                // camera
            if (item == 0) {

                imageFilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp_img.jpeg";

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/tmp_img.jpeg"));

                intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        mImageCaptureUri);

                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else { // pick from file
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
            }
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Now on `onActivityResult` you need to handle this according to your need.
Thanks

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you then don't forget to mark as answer so question could be close,and if you face any problem then do comment.